# Difference between **journalctl -u test.service** and **journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=test**

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald, docker-logs

I have a systemd service file which run a docker container with log driver journald.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run \
    --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} \
    -p ${PORT}:8080 \
    --add-host ${DNS} \
    -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
    --log-driver=journald \
    --log-opt tag="docker.{{.Name}}" \
    ${RESPOSITORY_NAME}/${CONTAINER_NAME}

ExecStop=-/usr/bin/docker stop ${CONTAINER_NAME}
```

When I check the logs via journalctl I see two different *_TRANSPORT*. 
With **journalctl -u test.service** I see *_TRANSPORT=stdout*. And with **Journalctl CONTAINER_NAME=test** I see *_TRANSPORT=journal*

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is in how the logs get to `systemd-journald` before they are logged.

As of right now, the supported transports (at least according to the `_TRANSPORT` field in `systemd-journald`) are: *audit, driver, syslog, journal, stdout* and *kernel* (see [systemd.journal-fields(7)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.journal-fields.html)).

In your case, everything logged to `stdout` by commands executed by the `ExecStart=` and `ExecStop=` directives is logged under the `_TRANSPORT=stdout` transport.

However, Docker is internally capable of using the [journald logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/journald/) which, among other things, introduces several custom journal fields - one of them being `CONTAINER_ID=`. It's just a different method of delivering data to `systemd-journald` - instead of relying on systemd to catch and send everything from stdout to `systemd-journald`, Docker internally sends everything straight to `systemd-journald` by itself.

This can be achieved by using the `sd-journal` API (as described in [sd-journal(3)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd-journal.html)). Docker uses the [go-systemd](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd/blob/master/journal/journal.go) Go bindings for the `sd-journal` C library.

Simple example:

`hello.c`

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <systemd/sd-journal.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello from stdout\n");
    sd_journal_print(LOG_INFO, "Hello from journald");

    return 0;
}
```

```
# gcc -o /var/tmp/hello -lsystemd hello.c
# cat > /etc/systemd/system/hello.service << EOF
[Service]
ExecStart=/var/tmp/hello
EOF

# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl start test.service
```

Now if I check journal, I'll see both messages:

```
# journalctl -u hello.service
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-09-30 22:08:02 CEST, end at Fri 2020-03-27 17:11:29 CET. --
Mar 27 17:08:28 localhost systemd[1]: Started hello.service.
Mar 27 17:08:28 localhost hello[921852]: Hello from journald
Mar 27 17:08:28 localhost hello[921852]: Hello from stdout
Mar 27 17:08:28 localhost systemd[1]: hello.service: Succeeded.
```

But each of them arrived using a different transport:

```
# journalctl -u hello.service _TRANSPORT=stdout
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-09-30 22:08:02 CEST, end at Fri 2020-03-27 17:12:29 CET. --
Mar 27 17:08:28 localhost hello[921852]: Hello from stdout
```

```
# journalctl -u hello.service _TRANSPORT=journal
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-09-30 22:08:02 CEST, end at Fri 2020-03-27 17:12:29 CET. --
Mar 27 17:08:28 localhost systemd[1]: Started hello.service.
Mar 27 17:08:28 localhost hello[921852]: Hello from journald
Mar 27 17:08:28 localhost systemd[1]: hello.service: Succeeded.
```